# JSLINT warning about style or error about Conditional Expression

Tags: javascript, debugging, conditional-statements, expression, jslint

I'm trying to fix what JSLINT is warning about two things tha I don't know how to fix. Which line should be replaced with what code? I have pasted the code in question and the warnings about them below. Thanks very much in advance for your suggestion / answer.

**JSLINT says:**

*Problem at line 137: Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.*

`while(elem = document.getElementById("optionsDiv"+g))`

*Problem at line 140: Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'.*

`return g;`

---

```
function isAnyOptionVisible()
{
    var g=0;
    while(elem = document.getElementById("optionsDiv"+g))
    {
        if(elem.className==="optionsDivVisible")
            return g;
        g++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the conditional, except that `elem` may be a global if it isn't declared in an outer scope.  If it's not declared, do so before hand:

```
var elem, g=0;
```

If you want to make JSLint happy, you can add an explicit comparison to null:

```
while((elem = document.getElementById("optionsDiv"+g)) !== null)
```

I don't see anything  about "Expected {".  However, putting the g++ on the same line as the brace is odd style.

Remember that JSlint is partly about Crockford's personal preferences, which you don't always have to agree with.

EDIT: Okay, the second error is because JSLint wants you to put the return in braces, e.g.:

```
    if(elem.className==="optionsDivVisible")
    {
        return g;
    }
    g++;
```

This is also the style I prefer to code in.  I do find that it avoids certain errors.  However, this is again subjective.  The obvious tradeoff is that it adds two lines.

Comment: +1 Mattjew, sorry I accidentally put my own test version, please see the old code sothat the mistake is more clear ( I just placed a bracket somewhere on random which should not have been in my quesion)  Curious to your possible change of answer and better placement of the curly bracket, if at all!

Comment: Awesome @Matthew  thanks!  PS your name reminds me of my favourite character from the american comedy XNYX NewsRadio. Its like Seinfield better understood by intelligent audiences. Ever heard of WNYX NewsRadio?

Comment: @Sam, heard of it, but never watched.